# after redirect, other functions are not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc

I am new to jQuery, please help.

After window.location.href other functions are not getting called/ aborted.

I am using Spring to catch that url("downloadPack?Name=" + Name + "&ID="+ID) and generating excel file , till this point it is working fine.

below code works perfectly on Firefox and IE , but having issues with Google Chrome only.

```
var href_red = "downloadPack?Name=" + Name + "&ID="+ID ;


                    jQuery
        .post(
                'checkPack',
                {
                    Name :Name,
                    ID : ID,
                    Date :Date,

                    },
                function(data) {
                    if (data == 1) {
                        window.location.href = href_red;

                        dialog_load('Download Workbook','downloadOptions', '675px', '630px', 2);



                    } else {
                        dialog_error('Error','workbook has not yet been created, please create it first');
                    }

                });
```

Comment: You forgot to properly build 'href_red'. Semi colon should be after 'navDate'.

Comment: that's typo , please ignore it.I have update my code

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `window.location` will kill all scripts currently running in the browser.

So you need to add that code before you are redirecting.

Or other solution is getting a page via AJAX and run a callback function to execute when the content is loaded.

Comment: I tried changing order of the call still not working ..
can you please give sample example for Ajax call..